# Get the MAX of combined CASE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 CASE statements and I want to know how can I only display the MAX of the calculation.

I have tried combining my CASE statements with the COALESCE function.

```
SELECT
ID,
CASE 
    WHEN tw.displayText IN ('A','B','C') THEN 'A1'
    WHEN tw.displayText IN ('D','E','F') THEN 'A2'
    WHEN tw.displayText IN ('G','H','I') THEN 'A3'
    ELSE NULL
    END AS COL1
```

How can I make `COL1` be `A3` if the `ID` can take all 3 (`A1`,`A2`,`A3`)

```
ID COL1
1  A1
1  A2
1  A3

ID COL1
1  A3
```

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense.   If `tw.displayText = '1,2,3'` then none of the CASES are true, and the result would be NULL.

Comment: Not sure why you are using coalesce here. Just multiple WHENs would do the job. But not sure what the last part "tw.displayText is 1, 2, and 3 then I want COL1 to be A3" means. Also your coalesce is missing a final value if all three are NULL.

Comment: *if  tw.displayText is 1, 2, and 3* tw.displayText can't be all 1, 2 and 3 at the same time. It has only 1 value 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: So finally you just need `select id, max(col1) from tablename group by id`?

Answer (score 1):

Although the wording of your question is unclear, if my mind-reading skills are on point today, I think this is all you need:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN tw.displayText IN ('G','H','I') THEN 3 
  WHEN tw.displayText IN ('D','E','F') THEN 2
  WHEN tw.displayText IN ('A','B','C') THEN 1 
  ELSE NULL
END AS COL1
```

Why?  Because a single CASE expression is evaluated such that the first WHEN (from top to bottom) to evaluate as true is the one that will be returned by the expression.  The rest will be ignored.

So in this expression, if the conditions that would result in a "3" are true, then "3" is returned and the other conditions are ignored.   If "3" isn't true, then the conditions for "2" are checked.   And so on.

Now if you plan on using GROUP BY and actually getting an Aggregate, then you would need to wrap this entire CASE..END expression in a MAX() function.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't have a `greatest()` or `least()` function.  But you can do this in the `from` clause using `apply`:

```
select COL1
from tw cross apply
     (select max(val) as col1
      from (values (CASE WHEN tw.displayText IN ('A','B','C') THEN 1 END),
                   (CASE WHEN tw.displayText IN ('D','E','F') THEN 2 END),
                   (CASE WHEN tw.displayText IN ('G','H','I') THEN 3 END)
           ) v(val)
     ) v;
```

There may be other ways to phrase this.  This is a pretty general solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want only one `case` expression with `max()` :

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN tw.displayText IN ('A','B','C') THEN 1
                THEN 1
                WHEN tw.displayText IN ('D','E','F') THEN 2
                THEN 2
                WHEN tw.displayText IN ('G','H','I') THEN 3
                THEN 3
           END) AS COL1
```

`MAX()` is really unnecessary because `case` expression only return single value & will evaluate only once whenever any of them conditions are mat.